# MaskFormatter of jFormattedTextField deletes inserted value

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield, maskformatter

I created a format for my *jFormattedTextField*

```
MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("###.###.###.###");
formatter.setValidCharacters("0123456789");
jFormattedTextField7 = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField(formatter);
```

but anytime I try to insert a value in the *jFormattedTextField*, switching to another one to insert an input value, the one in the code gets empty again.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You haven't entered a number in each position, therefore it is considered invalid. Try:

```
textField.setFocusLostBehavior(JFormattedTextField.COMMIT);
```

Comment: it does not allow me to write anything, now.

Comment: @JackLametta, Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. So you need a JFrame with your JFormattedTextField and some other component that you can tab to.